# Is it possible that LXML can detect what value a class has in HTML?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, lxml

So for example I have something like this:

```
<button class="oW_lN oF4XW sqdOP yWX7d    _8A5w5   ">MyTextIsHere</button>
```

The **"MyTextIsHere"** section **can have only 2 different text for example: "Yes" and "No"**, would it be possible to somehow check out which value is at the given moment? The page reloads after every action.

Or something else that would work? I am using Python.

Comment: Update the question with a bit of the _outerHTML_

Answer (score 0):

Using *Selenium* you can easily extract the *text* **Yes** or **No** using either of the following solutions:

- Using `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- Using `text`:

  ```
  myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath").text
  ```